# ng-grid changing first string character in Uppercase in cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a ng-grid in my application and I should capitalize the word in ng-grid's cell, so that first character would in uppercase.
How should I do it?

I tried to use `cellTemplate` property in that field in ng-grid like following:

```
field : 'myField',                            
                        displayName : '',                        
                        cellTemplate : '<div class="ngCellText" ng-style="{\'text-transform\':capitalize;}">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>'                                                
                      }, {
```

When testing `'text-transform':capitalize` in ordinary HTML page it works.
But in `cellTemplate` not at least code like above.

Have anyone ideas how define it into ng-grid?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'cellTemplate' to change first letter case. Instead of writing separate function change cellTemplate like:

```
{
  cellTemplate: '<div>{{row.entity[col.field].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+
             row.entity[col.field].substring(1)}}</div>' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `text-transform: capitalize` transforms the first character of each word to uppercase, not just the first word…so that may not be exactly what you want; however, if you do want the first character of every word capitalized, you would need to write the cell template like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0].cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex() style="text-transform:capitalize;">{{COL_FIELD}}</div>';
```

If you want to transform only the first character of the entire cell contents to be capitalized, then you could use a filter like this:

```
app.filter('capitalize', function () {
  return function (input, scope) {
    if (input != null) {
      return input.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
    }
  }
});

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0].cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()>{{COL_FIELD | capitalize}}</div>';
```

Or as a third option, you could use CSS and the [`::first-letter`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-letter) pseudo element, like this:

```
div.myCellClass::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0].cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText myCellClass" ng-class="col.colIndex()>{{COL_FIELD}}</div>';
```